# Which victims were the killers individually responsible for murdering?

Tags: plot-explanation, scream

It is revealed in [*Scream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scream_(1996_film)) that Billy Loomis and Stu Macher were in a partnership to terrorize and murder the people of Woodsboro.

The final scene of the film shows Billy and Stu confessing their crimes to Sidney Prescott while attempting to frame Sidney's father for all of the murders.

Stu and Billy were responsible for [six](http://scream.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Count_(Movies)) murders if you count Maureen Prescott the year before:

1. Maureen Prescott
2. Steven Orth
3. Casey Becker
4. Principal Himbry
5. Tatum Riley
6. Kenny Jones

During the murder scenes that were shown on film, there was always only one masked killer shown.  This leads the viewer to believe that Billy and Stu (while still partners in their crime spree) worked alone during the murders.

**Is there any information that tells us who killed who?  Which victims did Stu murder?  Which victims did Billy Murder?**

**Is there any out of universe explanation from filmmakers explaining which victims that Billy and Stu were responsible for killing?**

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Mathew Lillard's character was the primary killer, especially for the deaths that occur at the house at the end since Skeet Ulrich's character was fake murdered and was on the bed upstairs during most of the carnage. I think it makes sense to assume that he was the killer in all the other deaths as well.

Comment: @sanpaco Hmmm.  Why did his girlfriend say that he was with her all night the night before then?  I would think that Billy killed Casey and Steve in the beginning.  Remember during lunch the next day when Tatum (Stu's girlfriend) says that Stu was with her all night?  She had no reason to lie about that.

Comment: IIRC, Billy admitted to killing Maureen Prescott (sidney's mom) because she was having an afair with billy's dad, causing his mom to leave them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no word from screenwriter about who killed who. So, there is no out-of-universe explanation for this one.

Therefore, we will go through each murder and conclude who killed who.

### 1. Maureen Prescott:

It was Billy as he later admits it near the end of the movie.

### 2. Steve and Casey:

They were murdered by Stu while Billy did the calling. It is Billy who has been the mastermind of all these killings and he is also obsessed with movies as we can see later when he and Sidney have sex.

Stu must've killed them both when Billy signaled him.

### 3. Attack on Sidney:

This time also Stu attacked and Billy called, because Billy can't get all the way down the stairs, change the outfit and climb from the window. We can also see that Billy dropped the phone when he hugged Sidney.

### 4. Himbry:

He was killed by Billy. Since Stu was busy inviting people and doing preparations for the party, he can't kill Himbry.

### 5. Tatum:

Of course, it was Billy who killed her. Stu was the host of the party and he'd have been noticed if he had gone to kill her.

### 6. Kenny:

Stu killed him while Billy played dead.

All those attacks were done by Stu since Billy played fake death upstairs until he reveals the murders.

In conclusion, Billy killed Tatum, Himbry and Maureen Prescott while Stu killed Steve, Casey and Kenny.

There are also list a on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls074727382/) and a thread on [Wikia](http://scream.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:38733) for who killed who in Scream.

Comment: I'm not sure about #1, just because Tatum says that Stu was with her all night.

Comment: @steelershark No. Tatum says that Stu was with her last night, not all night. When Tatum said he was with her last night, Randy asked him if he was before or after Steve was sliced and diced.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).