# Who attacked and murdered who in Scream (2022)?

Tags: scream-2022

In *Scream* (2022) AKA *Scream 5*, it was revealed that it was

> Richie and Amber

that were behind the Ghostface attacks and murders.

In the film, only one of the murders was admitted by the murderer themself:

> Amber: I was the last thing Dewey saw before he died too.

Since only one murder was confirmed to be done by the individual responsible, I'm wondering who was behind the Ghostface mask when the other victims were attacked or murdered.

Are there statements from those involved in the making of the film about who attacked and killed who? Is there evidence shown in the film itself that will allow the audience to conclude who is the attacker or murderer for each victim?

<sup>(Inspired by this question for the original *Scream* (1996): [Which victims were the killers individually responsible for murdering?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62458/1006))</sup>