# Who attacked and killed who in Scream VI (2023)?

Tags: scream-vi

In *Scream VI* (2023), the identities of the Ghostface killers were revealed to be

> Wayne Bailey, Quinn Bailey, and "Ethan Landry".

The film did not explicitly show who was behind the mask for every murder. Only some of the killings were confessed by one of the culprits:

> **Quinn**: It was a good way to get off the suspect list.
> Stab Gale Weathers, stab Mindy on the train.
> That sort of thing.

This leaves some ambiguity about who attacked or killed the other victims.

Are there any statements from the filmmakers or the cast about who attacked and killed who? Are there any clues or hints in the film itself that can help the viewers deduce who was wearing the mask in each Ghostface attack or murder scene?

<sup>(Inspired by this question for the original *Scream* (1996): [Which victims were the killers individually responsible for murdering?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62458/1006))</sup>